# Fastest way to compute a determinant from a LaTeX matrix input

Tags: matrices, determinant, math-software

I have this input, coming from a LaTeX document:

```
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
-2 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
-1 & 2 & -1 & 3 \\ 
0 & 1 & 3 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
```

What's the shortest path to get its determinant, with a PC/Windows?

1. Use an online service (which one) ?
2. Import it to Maple (my Maple 7 doesn't seem to recognize it when I copy/paste this LaTeX)
3. Another software available on this platform? (that can do this in a few clicks: import from LaTeX, compute determinant, display result)

Note: I don't want to have to manually copy each coefficient into a new Maple matrix / don't want to manually copy each coefficient into an online tool; I was looking for something that would work with a copy/paste of the LaTeX definition of the matrix.

Comment: Are the matrices usually $4\times 4$ or smaller? If so, you can usually just use any online calculator. In general, finding determinant can be a serious task.

Comment: @ElliotG I think the OP wants a calculator that will allow him to paste in the LaTeX source. That would be valuable if there are lots of determinants to find. If just one or two it's not worth the trouble of a search.

Comment: @ElliotG Yes 5x5 maximum. The thing is: I don't want to have to manually copy each coefficient into a new Maple matrix/ don't want to manually copy each coefficient into an online tool; I was looking for something that would work with a copy/paste of the LaTeX definition of the matrix. Why? I usually have *lots* of matrices (I'm preparing exams for my students)...

Comment: Ah, in that case this may be better suited for the Tex SE. I think it is possible though.

Comment: @ElliotG Hum, not really Tex SE I think (moreover they are very very fast to close questions if not strictly Tex ;)), it's rather a math computation problem (with only input coming from Tex).

Comment: see here https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-write-a-2-by-2-matrix-determinant-formula-in-LaTex

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner No, I don't want to write the formula, I just want the numerical result ;)

Comment: Someone on TeX.se might be interested enough to write the evaluation code in TeX - possible but not fun. You could also consider entering your matrix in the computational software, evaluating, and copying to TeX. I think Mathematica outputs TeX; Maple too. Or have TeX write the matrix to an external file, input to python, then grab the output. Then your document would be up to date when you recompile, even when you change the entries.

Comment: @EthanBolker: the question would be: how to *input* a matrix (in Tex format) into Maple?

Comment: I was proposing a different workflow. You have to type the matrix once somewhere. You could start in Maple rather than in TeX. If the matrices are already written you could write a script to parse them and put them in Maple format.

Comment: @MorganRodgers Good idea, I'll find how to parse it via Python (can be done in < 20 lines I think), but I was really hoping that in 2018, LaTeX matrix code, `copy`,  math software, `paste`, boom, done! :)

Comment: @WillJagy Maybe does a recent version of Maple allow that natively, in 2 seconds?

Comment: The venerable text editor Emacs comes with a computer algebra system called `calc` that understands various input formats including LaTeX. If you happen to edit your LaTeX files in Emacs, this is probably the most convenient way.

Comment: @OmarAntolín-Camarena good idea! (unfortunately mostly use SublimeText).

Comment: A possible two-step process would be to paste into Cygwin running `sed -e 's/&//g' -e 's/\\\\/;/g'` and then paste the result from Cygwin into Maple in between `[ ]`.  (Of course, that reformats to Matlab/Octave matrix syntax; if Maple matrix syntax is different, you might need to adjust.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an online solution, usable directly in browser:

[How to compute a determinant with Javascript, with input as a LaTeX input format?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48797282/1422096)

It looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's [an online Sage Cell](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxtTrsKwzAQ2w3-h-OGYtMk5NGlQ-mHxBlc4hRD7JjLDYXSf69JWujQQSAkISlYXpngAoSIUpibu_v4TMEy-cdLigYO0GZ0GScwBqQo2z_aN7eRbhfrTJtPrsndLo4_zdueD2khBnJS7Ibqg03KRy7IVZOPo51nheW1r8vzcMQCSGuYFgICHyFs76s1zZ4VoTGoB12NjpV-A9jYOTk=&lang=sage) that does it. Just replace the example LaTeX matrix with your own.

Answer (score 0):

[Wolfram Alpha reads LaTeX input syntax](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=%5Cbegin%5C%28123%29pmatrix%5C%28125%29%0A1+%26+2+%26+3+%26+4+%5C%5C+%0A-2+%26+2+%26+3+%26+4+%5C%5C+%0A-1+%26+2+%26+-1+%26+3+%5C%5C+%0A0+%26+1+%26+3+%26+1%0A%5Cend%5C%28123%29pmatrix%5C%28125%29).